# Service doesn't start on boot

Tags: shell, systemd

I created following service in `/etc/systemd/system/conkyAutostart.service`

```
[unit]
Description=Conky Autostart

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/AutostartScripts/conkyAutostart.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the shell script mentioned in ExecStart looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
conky &
```

afterwards I type in

```
systemctl enable conkyAutostart.service

systemctl start conkyAutostart.service
```

no error messages show up, now I type in `systemctl` and see that 'conkyAutostart.service' has the status:

```
LOAD: loaded

ACTIVE: failed

SUB: failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This covers the same ground as http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228916/ already has.

Comment: @JdeBP please vote to close when you find a duplicate. The comment is very unlikely to be seen by enough people to close the question and, if you vote to close, the OP is shown a button that lets them close it directly.